# Why has development asp.net permanently high cpu load?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, cpu-usage

**PROBLEM**

I use typically development asp.net - now on whole new powerful machine install everything new for it "Visual Studio Community Edition 2013". After run project with "View in Browser" or "Start Debugging" every request hit cpu to permanently high load ~80%.

Q what is wrong and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLUTION

Miscrosoft came up with a feature called "Browser Link" in 2013 which is enabled by default, [see more here](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link).
Altought there are already exist some time but it may be difficult to notice if you change from "VS 2010 PRO" or "VS 2012 WEB".

To turn off you can use 2 choices:

1. disable it in gui
2. disable it in web.config

Because we want it turn off permanently for portability project add this to "web.config"

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
      <add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false"/>
    <appSettings>
</configuration>
```

[See more here](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link#disabling)

Comment: THANK YOU! This was driving me nuts.

Comment: @Ondrej my pleasure :-)